# network programming management-UNIX

Tags: sockets, unix

under what conditions a socket is ready for reading and writing?

Comment: what have you tried so far? (IOW, what is your programming question, do you have a language, ....)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the excellent Beej's guide to network programming [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). Worthy read...

Answer (score 0):

After the socket binds to a IP address and port, its ready to read/write.
Is your question specific for any language ?

Answer (score 0):

On a server, you would usually do in order:

- [socket()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) - Create socket
- [bind()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) - Bind the socket to a specific port
- [listen()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) - Listen for incoming request
- [accept()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) - Accept the request

So, in this situation, your socket would be ready for reading and writing after passing and on successful `accept()`

On a client side:

- [socket()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket) - Create socket
- [connect()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/connect) - Make connection to another peer

So here, it would be ready if it passes and on successfull `connect()`.